# Rails sanitise and validate input from user for where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following code which I am using to filter the result of the posts based on the user's search. How do i ensure that the parameters are present, valid, and sanitised?

```
Post.where("title LIKE ? AND cost >= ? AND cost <= ? AND status = 'open'", "%#{search_params[:keywords]}%",
                    "#{search_params[:min] && !search_params[:min].empty? ? search_params[:min] : 0}",
                    "#{search_params[:max] && !search_params[:max].empty? ? search_params[:max] : 999999999}");
```

Comment: The `#sanitize_sql_for_conditions` method should come in handy here - [see docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_for_conditions)

Answer (score 0):

There are - as usual - a handful of ways to go about this.

The best in my opinion is to [use a form model](http://culttt.com/2015/11/04/using-form-objects-in-ruby-on-rails/). Good gems to help implementing this pattern are [virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) and [reform](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform) but you can just as well use [plain ActiveModel](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects).

The idea is that the form object does the validation and if it is not valid, the controller can render the validation errors.

If you search the web for "Rails form model pattern" or similar, you'll find a few more articles. Here's another one that looks well-written: https://webuild.envato.com/blog/creating-form-objects-with-activemodel-and-virtus/

On a related note, you might want to encapsulate this complex query in a scope or - if your application is going to grow - even a Query Object. See [this article](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) for a few more advanced patterns that can be of advantage in more complex Rails applications.

Regarding sanitization of the input, as long as you're using parameter binding and not manual string concatenation, Rails will automatically sanitize the input to prevent SQL injection. If you want to do more - like removing stop words from a search query or sth. like that, you're probably better off with a pre-existing search framework like [sphinx](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx), [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) or [textacular](https://github.com/textacular/textacular).

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by combinating several scopes with some conditions:

```
# in your models/post.rb
scope :min_cost, ->(cost) {
  cost = 0 if cost.blank?
  where('cost >= ?', cost)
}
scope :max_cost, ->(cost) {
  cost = 999_999_999 if cost.blank?
  where('cost <= ?', cost)
}
scope :cost_between, ->(min, max) { min_cost(min).max_cost(max) }
scope :open, -> { where(status: 'open') }
scope :search, ->(title) { where("title LIKE ?", "%#{title}%") if title }
```

An use this scopes like this in your controller:

```
Post.open.search(search_params[:keywords])
        .cost_between(search_params[:min], search_params[:max])
```